# CGRectMake alternative

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, cgrect, cgrectmake

I have seen this alternative to using `CGRectMake()` in order to initialise a `CGRect` variable:

> CGRect frame = (CGRect){0,0,10,10};

My question is, how does `CGRect frame = (CGRect){0,0,10,10};` work? What's going on behind the scenes? It looks like a c-style array is being initialised (`{x,y,w,h}`) which is then being cast as a `CGRect` struct - is this correct? If so, how is it possible to cast a c style array as a struct?

N.B. I am not asking if it is appropriate to use the above alternative to `CGRectMake()`, I only wish to understand why/how it works.

Comment: It simply works if the two statements create the same sequence of bytes. 

However, I am confused that you are using 0 and 10 instead of 0.0 and 10.0. 0 and 10 would be compiled as integer constants and 0.0 and 10.0 would be come out als float/double constants. Tehrefore I doubt that you could use float as a legal frame for anything useful. 

CGRect is a stucture made of CGPoint and CGSize. Both of them are made of two CGFload members (x and y in the case of CGPoint and width and height in the case of CGSize).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a so-called compound literal. You can read more about them in this article by Mike Ash: [Friday Q&A 2011-02-18: Compound Literals](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-02-18-compound-literals.html).

Answer (score 1):

U can use like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(@"{{0, 0}, {612, 892}}"); // it contents { CGPoint origin;CGSize size;};
NSLog(@"rect : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
CGPoint origin = {10, 20};
CGSize size = {100, 200};
CGRect rect = {origin, size};
```